# how can I implement zlib.compress in java

Tags: java, python

I would like to rewrite python code to java . This is python code:

```
        zipped = zlib.compress(data_json_upload.encode("utf-8"))
        print ("data encode")
        print (zipped)
        base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(zipped)
        base64_string = base64_bytes.decode('utf-8')
```

and This is  my java code :
  *

```
        byte[] bytes = inputString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream os = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
        os.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        os.close();
        byte[] result = baos.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(result);
        byte [] base64=Base64.encodeBase64(result);
        String send= new String(base64,"UTF-8");
```

*
however they seems to be return different results  for the same string any idea what can I change to get the same code is working on java ?
For example send  in java not the same as   base64_string in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GZIPOutputStream` will produce a `*.gz` file. If you just need a zlib stream, use [`DeflaterOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html) instead.

```
    // ... the rest are the same ...
    DeflaterOutputStream os = new DeflaterOutputStream(baos);
    // ... the rest are the same ...
```

Comment: Thank you it was helpful